# Recalling function: Tensor 'object' is not callable

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

Suppose I have a function named `test` as follows:

```
def test(X,W):
    ..do stuff
    return stuff
```

which I call using `model = test(X,W)`.

When I call the function the first time, I do not get an error. But, if I call the function again, I get the error `'Tensor' object is not callable`. Essentially the calling code looks like this:

```
model = test(X,W)
model1 = test(X,W)
```

and I get the error at the call for `model1`.

I would like to not need to redefine the function again before making another call to that function. After quite a while of researching this, I still have not found a solution.

How can I modify my function or calls to it in order to be able to recall the function?

Comment: Do you call the functions straight after each other? Or is there some other code inbetween?

Comment: @DavidG Originally, there was other code in between. But, in the process of debugging, I moved the functions together and called them straight after each other. Both calling the functions straight after each other and with some in between causes the mentioned error. I am using a Jupyter notebook so I do not know if that has something to do with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could see a situtation in which this happens if you name a variable the same as your function (within the "....more stuff here" section) meaning it would work the first time you call it, but would fail the second time. Take the following simplified example:

```
def test(x,y):
    global test
    test = x / 2 # random calculation
    return x + y

model = test(5,5)
model1 = test(10,10)
```

This would produce an error very similar to the one in the question:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SO.py", line 43, in <module>
    mode2 = test(10,10)
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

The solution would be to avoid naming variables the same as your functions.

Comment: Yes, I had a variable the same name as my function. I can't believe that I over looked that. Thanks so much!