# Pytorch nn.BCELoss() getting TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not callable

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor, loss-function

I am using `adv_loss = torch.nn.BCELoss()` to calculate loss for my network:

When I call the function the first time(first batch), I do not get an error. But, if I call the function 2nd time(2nd batch), I get the error `'Tensor' object is not callable.`

I am training GAN, where `output_of_nn_layers = D(img1)`(output of discriminator network) and

`label = torch.ones(batch, 1, device=device, dtype = torch.float32)`

I am using adv_loss(BCELoss) in generator training as well, but error occurs in 2nd batch. So total times it is used in training 1st batch is 3 times(2 times for discriminator and 1 time for generator).

```py
for i, (img1, img2) in enumerate(dataloader):
  #do some processing
  loss = adv_loss(output_of_nn_layers, label)
  #do some processing
```

I am getting error : `TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not callable`

Full error log:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-52-bafb0a65d4d9> in <module>()
     73       val_real = D(dis_train_real)
     74       print("check4.2")
---> 75       d_real_loss = adv_loss(val_real, real_label)   #BCELoss
     76       print("check4.3")
     77       val_fake = D(dis_train_fake)

TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not callable
```

I found similar question on stackoerflow : [Recalling function: Tensor 'object' is not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48819022/recalling-function-tensor-object-is-not-callable)

It gave solution that called function should not have variable name same as function name. Am i missing something here?

i also tried using `nn.L1Loss()` and got same error.
what does this error means? what can i do to remove it?

Comment: Can you show what your `output_of_nn_layers` and `label` are?

Comment: I have added more details.

Comment: Can you also include the full error log?

Comment: @ThomasSchillaci added full error log.

Comment: What does `print(type(val_real))` and `print(type(real_label))` yields on line 74?

Comment: <class 'torch.Tensor'>  for both of them.

Comment: Are you declaring a variable named `adv_loss` somewhere else than when calling `adv_loss = torch.nn.BCELoss()`?

Comment: Thank you. after you mentioned, I checked whole program again and adv_loss was declared again in later part of training procedure.